# How to set different dependency classes and scopes for the WebApplication and HostedService in the dot net 6.0

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am working on Asp.net core **WebApplication** in which I am also running a background service **AppServiceWorker**. I need to register different dependency classes and scopes for **AppServiceWorker** and **WebApplication**. My Progarm.cs is like this

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
// code for register Dependency
builder.Services.AddHostedService<AppServiceWorker>();
var app = builder.Build();
// code for register Middleware
app.Run();
```

Because dependencies are registered in a single point for both **WebApplication** and **AppServiceWorker**. So how can I achieve different dependency classes and scopes for two different worker?

Comment: Maybe some design pattern can solve your problem?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Is it about minor differences or about a large set of dependencies you want to change? In an extreme case, you could run two separate hosts in the application, one for the web application, the other for the hosted service. If there are only some types that you want to change, you could use some marker interfaces.